# How to use Excel-VBA to pick up a date from a web popup calendar?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on VBA code in the last step to fill a web form. The problem is that the cell value which I passed to the date field does not match the format. Even if I try to pass string "yyyy-mm-dd".
When I click the field there is a popup calendar for picking up a date.

Below is my codes and web html and screenshot:

Error:[image: Error]
HTML Code:[image: HTML Code]

```
     Sub AuditBookings()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim i, j, n As Integer
    Dim DataWs As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange, CFRange As Range
    Dim WebCF, WebCODate As String
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://xxx/ebkassembly/login.aspx"
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
    Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    If IE.LocationURL <> "https://xxx/Ebooking/Entry/Index2.aspx" Then 'check login URL
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("userName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B1").Value 'fill the username
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("userPwd").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B2").Value  'fill the password
        HTMLDoc.getElementById("accSubmit").Click
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
        IE.navigate "https://xxx/ebksettlement/HotelAudit/hotelAuditIndex.aspx"
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Else
        IE.navigate "https://xxx/ebksettlement/HotelAudit/hotelAuditIndex.aspx"
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    End If
    Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CtripReport")
    DataWs.Activate
    i = 1
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("pendingtb")
    n = HTMLTable.Children(0).Children.Length 'get QTY of unaudited bookings
    For i = i To n - 1
        WebCF = HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(7).all(0).innerText 'get confirmation number from web
        If WebCF <> "" Then
             Set DataRange = DataWs.Range("K2", "K" & n)  'set search range
             Set CFRange = DataRange.Find(what:=WebCF, lookat:=xlPart)'start matching
              If Not CFRange Is Nothing Then
                     CFRange.Select
                     HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(1).all(5).Click 'click check-out button
                     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                     'HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(3).all(3).Value = CFRange.Offset(0, -4).Value  ' fill check-out date
                     HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(3).all(3).Click
                     HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(3).all(3).Value = "2019-08-27"
                     HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(4).all(1).innerText = CFRange.Offset(0, -3).Value  ' fill guest name
                     HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(6).all(0).Value = CFRange.Offset(0, -1).Value  ' fill room number
                     'HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(7).all.innerText = CFRange.Value  ' fill confirmation number
                     'HTMLTable.Children(0).Children(i).Children(9).all(1).Click  ' click save button
              End If
        End If
     Next
      'MsgBox "Total " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CtripReport").Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count & " records are scraped"
 End Sub
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks Michael, first time sign-in this website.  trying edit and put links.

Comment: Please do not upload code as images, paste in the question as plain text, and format as code

Comment: @Luuklag, Thanks, finally, i get the paste the code successfully.

Comment: I try to '.removeAttribute ("readonly")' but no luck.

Comment: I can send a click action to make the canlendar pop up, how to select or pick a date ?

Comment: Finally，I figure out， case closed